# Stop VS2010 asking about remap url on solution load

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with several web applications in it. After switching to VS2010, it keeps asking me if I want to remap the web application urls to the physical location of the solution (which is different as there are several versions in development).
Most of the time I want to just run the gui and I don't care about the web side. It's rather annoying as it blocks the solution loading.

How can I make it stop asking me about it every time I load a different version of the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried installing the latest VS 2010 service pack?

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594453/visual-studio-2010-automatically-update-iis-physical-path-when-opening-a-diffe) addresses a similar issue (at least it sounded similar to me) and the selected answer recommended getting the service pack from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691.

Comment: As Brent Arias said, you may be able to find a solution by using Cassini or IIS Express. Or you may try opening Visual Studio with Administrative privileges. Right-click on the VS 2010 icon, then select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to create another (or modify one) of the solution files and right-click unload (not remove) the web project if you are not using it most of the time.

Comment: That would still be rather inconvenient every time I did wanted to use the server side, and will cause problems if common functions, that the server side also uses, won't be modified or compiled during regular development, due to the project being offline.

Answer (score 1):

As long as some projects are configured for debugging through IIS hosting (project properties->web) you'll get this nuisance.  Do these steps:

1. Change the configuration on that tab to no longer use IIS; choose the VS web development server (Cassini) instead.
2. On the same tab, uncheck the "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)"
3. Save, check-in, and sync everywhere.

In fact, even choosing to use IIS Express in the above sequence might also do the job.